# Does mongodb return documents in an array when I use the .find() method

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

my question is if I use

```
List.find({},function(err,listItems){
});
```

does it return all the documents I have inside the db and put in the callback function as an array which is the listItems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's just a name of the variable used in the callback

Syntax - first argument is the filter means find condition

Second argument is callback - it contains results matches your condition

In your case, listItems will have documents with all data as you have match All condition I.e empty condition.

I suggest you to try it out.

Comment: My bad, let me rephrase it. so if it finds all the matching documents, does the callback function(in this case "listItems")  basically becomes an array that contains all the documents it found?

Comment: To be more clear, when I say second argument it is the function. Function has two args. And your understanding is correct with respect to list items.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming `List` is a model you defined. See the [Mongoose find docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) for examples like this:

```
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});
```

If using the [MongoDB driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/) directly, it'd look similar. For example:

```
collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, docs) {})
```